# Moving emails with specific repicient

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to move email into a folder once read. I'm part of multiple DLs and I would like a macro that detects the DL in the To: field and moves the email to a specific folder. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub move2folder()
On Error Resume Next

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolderSrc = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.Folders("_Reviewed")

Set colItems = objFolderSrc.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")

For Each objMessage In colFilteredItems
objMessage.move objFolderDst
Next

End Sub
```

This moves the email to my desired folder once read however I'm not sure the syntax to have it recognize who the email was sent to. If this is not possible, could I have it detect the domain the email was sent from?

Answer (score 0):

Try InStr like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub move2folder()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Namespace
Dim objFolderSrc As Folder
Dim objFolderDst As Folder
Dim colItems As Items
Dim colFilteredItems As Items
Dim i As Long

'On Error Resume Next

'Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlook = Application
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolderSrc = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objFolderDst = objFolderSrc.Folders("_Reviewed")

Set colItems = objFolderSrc.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")


If colFilteredItems.count > 0 Then
    'For Each objMessage In colFilteredItems
    For i = colFilteredItems.count To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(colFilteredItems(i).To, "name of dist list") Then
            colFilteredItems(i).Move objFolderDst
        End If
    Next
End If

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objNameSpace = Nothing
Set objFolderSrc = Nothing
Set objFolderDst = Nothing
Set colItems = Nothing
Set colFilteredItems = Nothing

End Sub
```

Delete or move in reverse order.